# Why is my .data() function returning [ instead of the first value of my array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to pass an array into a jQuery data attribute on the server side and then retrieve it like so:

```js
var stuff = $('div').data('stuff');
alert(stuff[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-stuff="['a','b','c']"></div>
```

Why does this appear to alert '[' and not 'a' (see JSFiddle link)

**JSFiddle Link:** http://jsfiddle.net/ktw4v/3/

Answer (score 150, accepted):

It's treating your variable as a string, the zeroth element of which is `[`.

This is happening because your string is not [valid JSON](http://www.json.org/), which should use double-quotes as a string delimiter instead of single quotes.  You'll then have to use single-quotes to delimit the entire attribute value.

If you fix your quotation marks your original code works (see http://jsfiddle.net/ktw4v/12/)

```
<div data-stuff='["a","b","c"]'> </div>

var stuff = $('div').data('stuff');
```

When jQuery sees valid JSON in a data attribute it will [automatically unpack it for you](http://api.jquery.com/data#data2).

Comment: infact, ['a','b','c'] is NOT a valid JSON ;)

Comment: ['a','b','c'] is not valid JSON

Comment: What should the JSON look like?

Comment: It should use double quotes, but then you'd have to use single quotes to enclose the HTML attribute.

Comment: @Allen my original answer didn't spot the invalid JSON problem

Comment: Ah, well they should fix it because it does now :)  Glad someone knew the answer to this, it would have bugged me all day

Comment: @JoeBrockhaus they're both delimiters - quote marks are "string delimiters" and commas are "record delimiters".  Only the former are relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: This also works: `<div data-stuff="[&quot;a&quot;,&quot;b&quot;,&quot;c&quot;]"></div>`

Answer (score 16):

Declaring it as an attribute means that it is a string.

So `stuff[0]` would be equivalent to: `var myString = "['a','b','c']"; alert(myString[0]);`

You need to make it look like this:

```
<div data-stuff="a,b,c"></div>

var stuff = $('div').data('stuff').split(',');
alert(stuff[0]);
```

---

Retraction:  jQuery's parsing fails because it didn't meet the rules of parseJSON.

However, I will stand behind my solution.  There are aspects of the others that are less than ideal, just as this solution is less than ideal in some ways.  All depends on what your paradigms are.

Comment: no, declaring it as invalid JSON means that it's treated as a string.

Comment: @Alnitak - Although that may very well be the way that jQuery treats it -- I don't see that in the jQuery Api reference, and it most certainly isn't clear in the w3c spec.  As defining JSON in a dom object would break the w3c's 'neutrality', this appears to be a jQuery extension or, given the lack of documentation -- quirk.  At any rate, although I can't say that I agree with you on this point -- I'm not so peeved that I'm going to remove that first +1 you got.  : )

Comment: @John it _is_ documented in the jQuery API - "Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise it is left as a string."

Comment: @Alnitak Then I'm high, because I read pretty much the entire data section and many of the comments before posting.  I just looked again even.

Comment: @Alnitak ok, I found it from your edit.  Yes, this is a Jquery extension.  I'll ammend my post.

Comment: @Alnitak - And in my defense... this was buried in the 4th paragraph of the 2nd-form description.  : )

Comment: I'm choosing this as the answer, because  this will also simplify the html by removing the square bracket and double quotes. But also because I don't like using single quotes for attributes (dumb reason, since it's acceptable HTML).

Answer (score -3):

As others have identified the value is treated as string so it is returning "[". Please try this (aaa is the name of the div and I took out the data-stuff):

```
$(function(){
    $.data($("#aaa")[0],"stuff",{"aa":['a','b','c']});
    var stuff = $.data($("#aaa")[0],"stuff").aa;
    alert(stuff[0]); //returns "a"
});
```

Answer (score -4):

A different approach is posted at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktw4v/5/); `var stuff = $('div').data('stuff');` stuff is a string with 0th character as **'['**

Well, `var stuff = eval($('div').data('stuff'));` should get you an array

Comment: eval is evil :) there is always a better way

Comment: Please adjust your answer to say that, although a possible solution, eval() might cause unicorns to die... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea