# Twitter bootstrap typeahead does not work properly with data-source attribute

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

Why is it when i use the `"` sign in the `data-source` attribute to denote string values all works well but when i use `'` to denote them bootstrap is recognizing only the first character?

I know in c# and many other language the difference between `"` and `'` is the difference between a character and a string but its the first time i see it is strictly used in html is that the case here if so why isn't there any error in the JS.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <form>
            <div>
                <label>working typeahead</label>
                <input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" data-source='["hello","world"]' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>not working typeahead</label>
                <input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" data-source="['hello','world']" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H4Qmh/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is weird, but `data-source=["hello", "world"]` works, even that it doesn't look like clean HTML.

I'm wondering if it is being treated as JSON, in which case all elements must be wrapped in double-quotes. See: [How to pass an array into jQuery .data() attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071618/how-to-pass-an-array-into-jquery-data-attribute#answer-6071653).

Comment: You are correct sir, it's being treated as JSON and as such requires double quotes.  Try [linting](http://jsonlint.com/) the same array with both types.  `data-source=["hello", "world"]` works because [HTML attribute values don't require quotes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/syntax.html#attributes-0).