# js jQuery, is there a way to set/get multi value in attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set an attribute to an element that has multiple values. Is it possible?

I want to get the div element size (height, width) and set it inside an array and then set the array as the attribute value.

What I did is this:

```
function originBoxSize() {
    each('body div', function () {
        var boxSize = [$(this).css('height'), $(this).css('width')];// get the box size 
        $(this).attr('wcag-origin-box-size', boxSize); // set an new attr with boxsize value
    });

}
```

Now `boxSize` holds `["102px", "499px"]`

The `attr` looks like this:

```
wcag-origin-box-size="102px,499px"
```

When I want to get the `attr` value Im typing the line:

```
$('#element').attr('wcag-origin-box-size')
```

The result is this : `"102px,499px"` which is a string.

Is there a way to get only specific value from the attribute (height or width)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you just split the value with , ?     $('#element').attr('wcag-origin-box-size').split(",")[0] will give you the height.

Comment: Look at `getComputedStyle()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: I can do that, incase I wont succssed this way I will split, but Im sute there is a way to get/set multiple values

Comment: You could set each value to its own attribute.  Or serialize the array/object/etc. to a string, set that, and de-serialize it when reading it.  Or, as already suggested, just split the string (which is basically just a custom serialization).  An attribute itself can contain only one value, and that value is a string.

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mort3za/8s2z8dLw/6/

Answer (score 1):

The attribute value must be a string, so the browser converts the array into a string. Result of stringifying an array is equal to calling the `Array.prototype.join` method.

For converting the string into an array, you can reverse the process: split by `,`:

```
var array = value.split(',');
```

Another option that you have is using the jQuery [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method which can store an array as it is.

> The new data value [...] can be any Javascript type except `undefined`.

```
$(this).data('wcag-origin-box-size', boxSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a good answer for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071618/how-to-pass-an-array-into-jquery-data-attribute)

Basically you need to use [jQuery's data function](https://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of "attr", and give the data in a format that is JSON valid.

I fixed your code (which really wasn't far from the right way), and here is a working example:

```js
function originBoxSize() {
  $('body div').each(function() {

    // Get the box size 
    var boxSizeString = '["' + $(this).css('height') + '","' +
      $(this).css('width') + '"]';
    boxSize = JSON.parse(boxSizeString);

    // Set an new attr with boxsize value
    $(this).data('wcag-origin-box-size', boxSize);
  });
}

// Set all data-wcag-origin-box-size
originBoxSize();

// Show result
var a_size = $('#a').data('wcag-origin-box-size');
var b_size = $('#b').data('wcag-origin-box-size');
$('#a').html("<p>height: " + a_size[0] + "</p>" +
  "<p>width: " + a_size[1] + "</p>");
$('#b').html("<p>height: " + b_size[0] + "</p>" +
  "<p>width: " + b_size[1] + "</p>");
```

```css
div {
  margin: 3px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#a {
  height: 90px;
  width: 120px;
  background: red;
}
#b {
  height: 65px;
  width: 200px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `data` for this.

Something like

```
$(this).data('wcag-origin-box-size', boxSize);
```

Then, later fetch using

```
$('#element').data('wcag-origin-box-size');
```

See https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your way.

```
function originBoxSize() {
    each('body div', function () {
        var boxSize = [{height:$(this).css('height'),width:$(this).css('width')}];
        var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(boxSize);
        $(this).attr('wcag-origin-box-size', myJsonString ); 
    });

}

var myObject = JSON.parse($('#element').attr('wcag-origin-box-size'))
```

You can get values from the myObject:

```
var height = myObject[0].height;
var width = myObject[0].width;
```